# PHP array_walk_recursive mb_strtolower 2 d associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

I have such code

```
 <?php
    
    $array =
    [
        ['key_name' => 'Amazon Inc.', 'key_code' => '102923'],
        ['key_name' => 'Google inc, co io', 'key_code' =>'283923'],
        ['key_name' => 'IMSFT dcs', 'key_code' => '3384823'],
        ['key_name' => 'MSFTSurfshark io', 'key_code' =>'4473873']
    ];
    
    $search_text = 'mSfT';
    $lowText = strtolower($search_text); // to lower 
    $lowArr = array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$v) {$v = mb_strtolower(trim($v));}); // need convert to lower case whole array
    
    print_r($lowArr); // here is empty
    $r = array_filter($lowArr, function($el) use ($lowText) {return ( strpos($el['key_name'], $lowText) !== false );
    });
    
    $keys = array_keys($r); // all keys founded
    
    print_r( $r[$keys[0]]['key_code']); //return only first match
    
    ?>
```

When i want convert array to lower case
`$lowArr = array_walk_recursive($array, function ($v) {$v = mb_strtolower(trim($v));});`

then script return nothing using https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_intro

Goals is to find arrays elemnt by it key_name and return this element key_code

1. Why this happens?
2. If i use `$array = array_column($array, 'key_name', 'key_code');` how should look like php syntax for same things?

Comment: All this can be simplified to https://3v4l.org/mOYNH

Comment: @u_mulder which one will work faster?

Comment: Create tests and see. it's simple.

Answer (score 2):

Note this note in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

> If callback needs to be working with the actual values of the array, specify the first parameter of callback as a reference. Then, any changes made to those elements will be made in the original array itself.

So you need declare the parameter as a reference in order to make changes to the original array.

```
function (&$v) {$v = mb_strtolower(trim($v));}
```

Comment: This is not solve a problem, still return nothing

Comment: `array_walk_recursive` returns bool, not array, this changes the original array.

Comment: print_r($array)  still retun nothing

Comment: What do you mean nothing?

Comment: nothing i mean, no errors, no any output, emty

Comment: I don't have any problem with [this code](https://onlinephp.io?s=fZBBa8IwGIbvgfyH71CWForMpmBH7cYuEw87uZtICTHO0DYpX9OKyv670XlS8b2-PM8L7_Sj3baUBAJR7KGgZEkJ-CxZpfalEY1iULwD-2zEwRqYGzliMVxKadfXcvyavCWcreLH7Mza31qBNjIGaUHbWwNLMv5MMP9efP3AWnb305xnafYEPZOLHjfdVmD1aDpNJzybeAElq5ySyw_lTtRViUr22OlBhf_vxLDpjXTa3xC-BEMEx2CAAjqHztZ2pzB0qJvQN1H-F3lXi9q4Eq94lJ8A&v=8.1.11)

Comment: i use snippet https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_intro

Comment: So what about 2 question?

Comment: When I opened this link, I could see only one line of php code `echo "My first PHP script!";` So I tried copy my code to the editor then ran it, I got the expected results. And about question 2, if your aim is to find an alternative function for `array_column`, check mohanrajnr's note on [the array_column page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column)